# Найти все разрезы сети (графа)

Tags: python, алгоритм, графы

Есть сеть N (граф имеющий исток и сток) состоящая из k вершин.
Представленная в виде списка смежности (словарь).

```
N = dict()

k = int(input("Из скольки вершин состоит сеть? >> "))

for v in range(k):
    N[v] = [int(i) for i in input(f"В какие вершины есть ребро из {v}-й вершины? >> ").split()]

print(N)
```

Нужно найти все разрезы данной сети и вывести их.
Разрез - множество ребер, удалив которые сток (конечная вершина) будет недостижим. То есть удалив некоторые ребра графа (нужно найти как раз все варианты), мы никогда не сможем прийти от начальной вершины к конечной.

Answer (score 0):

Приходит а голову такой вариант - перечислить все подмножества графа, доступные из истока - да, их экспоненциальное количество, но ведь и разрезов тоже.

Для каждого подмножества проверить, является ли дополнение (набор остальных узлов) связным, и найти все дуги, которые **начинаются в узлах данного подмножества, и кончаются в узлах остатка** (множества-дополнения). Это и будет разрез.

Подводные камни наверняка есть - например, мне не вполне очевидно навскидку, что dfs или bfs дадут все связные подмножества из истока (их ещё, видимо, придётся проверять на уникальность, например - храня битовые маски проверенных)